# Node JS and ajax problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, notifications

I am trying to receive data through ajax from node.js but I am not sure what I am doing wrong between interacting the two.

Here is my ajax get request:

```
$.get('/notificationsNumber',  
        function (notify) {
            alert(notify);
            $('.notifications').html("Notifications " + 0).css("color","red")

    });
```

Here is my node.js file:

```
exports.notificationsNumber = function(req, res) {
    console.log('notifying start');
    Friend.findOne({userId: req.signedCookies.userid}, function(err,user) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            console.log('notifying err');
        } else {
            console.log('notifying');
            console.log(user.notifications);
            var notify = user.notifications;
            console.log(notify);
            res.send(notify);
        }
    });
};
```

UPDATE:

```
app.get('/notificationsNumber', user.notificationsNumber);
```

Here is the app.js code:

The alert is popping up the html doc of the page for some reason... and the line underneath it actually works correctly. Trying to connect the notify (which on the server side prints out the correct data).

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: the data is not displaying (notify) in the ajax call

Comment: Can you show the code where you add `notificationsNumber` to the router on the server?

Comment: Are you referring to the router file, because I included it right underneath the script file? If you are talking about the app.js file when I add it, it breaks the alert and all that

Comment: should it be `app.get('/notificationsNumber', exports.notificationsNumber);`?

Comment: no because user. (user calls the file that it is in which exports it) that part is correct... the only parts I can see having a problem is the jquery ajax get or  the way I am sending notify from the route file...

Comment: You should include the contents of the `alert(notify)` and also tell what you expected it to print. Otherwise we would have to guess what is going wrong.

Comment: The contents was un-readable and it was way too long, the problem was that res.send was incorrect and it had to be res.json when it sent

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was doing it as res.send it should be res.json...